Espresso UI Tests Fail to Display Components with 0dp Width or Height in ConstraintLayout
I am encountering an issue with my Android application's UI tests using Espresso. When I run a UI test, almost nothing is visible on the screen. However, when I normally launch the application on a device, everything is displayed correctly as expected.
It appears that Espresso UI tests cannot properly interpret the 0dp width or height value for the components set within a ConstraintLayout context, because when I change 0dp to match_parent it works! As a result, elements that rely on constraints to determine their size are not displayed during the tests.
Here are some details and steps I've taken:

the components have their constraints properly defined in the ConstraintLayout.

when the app runs on a device outside of Espresso, all elements are visible and correctly sized.

during tests, only some elements are displayed, while others (especially those with 0dp dimensions) are missing.


What I've Tried

used ActivityScenario to launch the activity in the test.
attempted to use IdlingResource to wait for the layout pass, but the issue persists.


How are you launching your app in your Espresso tests?  Is it using the same test device and intent that you would normally use?  Espresso doesn't "change" the UI in your app, it launches your app and instruments it.  I guess you could fiddle around with your app's UI, from your Espresso test, but I'm going to assume you aren't doing this.  Espresso also lets you inspect the view hierarchy for views that aren't even displayed.  Can you find your view by ID to determine if it's present in the view hierarchy?

I've spent hours on it and the solution was just updating a constraint layout library version...yeah.
